# Populating a list from a class with objects from other classes

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, printing, upcasting

I am having the next code arhitecture:

- class candybox with arguments flavor and origin which is the parent class for classes: Lindt, Baravelli and ChocoAmor which will have as a plus arguments: height, width(depending of the box)
- class CandyBag which needs to contain an Arraylist that will represent a gift containing 1 candybox of type Lindt, 1 candybox of type Baravelli and 1 candyboxe of type ChocoAmor.
  Now my problem is that I do not know how to populate the arraylist from class candybag with objects from the 3 classes: Lindt, Baravelli and ChocoAmor.

I thought of this:

```
import java.util.*;
class CandyBag extends CandyBox{

ArrayList<CandyBox> candybag = new ArrayList<CandyBox>();


CandyBox Austria_cherry = new Lindt(20, 5.4, 19.2); 
Candybox Italy_grape = new Baravelli(6.7,8.7);
Candybox France_coffee = new ChocAmor(5.5);

 
candybag.add(Austria_cherry);
candybag.add(Italy_grape);
candybag.add(France_coffee);


public void printArray(candybag){
 for(String item: candybag){
  System.out.println(item);
```

}
}

And then in main class just to create a candybag object and call printArray method:
CandyBag cadou = new CandyBag();
cadou.printArray(candybag); //i do not know exactly how to pass the arraylist from other class as parameter

Can you help me with this, how to print the arraylist with the 3 boxes?

Comment: You don't need to pass any list into that method. It's an instance method and therefor can access the field `ArrayList<CandyBox> candybag` of the instance the method is called on.

Comment: oh, and you can't just start writing method calls like `candybag.add(Austria_cherry);` into your class body. Those lines need to be inside a method or better yet a constructor.

Comment: What are the fields of each class that you pass into their constructor? Can you add the implementation of those classes for me to get a better idea of what you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the toString() method of each class to return the desired text. Also, the elements of `candybag` list are not string type.

```
for (CandyBox item: candyBag) {
    System.out.println(item.toString());
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(item.toString());` is not necessary and pretty much all you do is introduce a potential NullPointerException. As the javadoc of [println(Object x)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) says the method will call [String.valueOf(x)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) : *"if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned."* - So toString is already called by `System.out.println(item);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear and lacks all relevant codes. However I'll try to answer it as far as I understand.
What I understand of your goal is: You want to create inherited classes of `CandyBox` and finally a `CandyBag` class each of which can be represented as string in order to be able to print. Correct me if I get it wrong.
Well, I would suggest you to use `Object.toString` by extending the `Object` class and overriding the `toString` method.
Since I don't know the properties of the inherited classes like `Lindt` I just added `height` and `width` properties to be able to implement this example. So let's get into it...

First we would implement the base class `CandyBox`. Normally it should inherit from the `Object` class implicitly. But in case of it don't, you should extend it explicitly. In the base class we will override the `toString` method to implement our logic so that it can create a string containing its name and its properties.
But note that we declare an abstract method named `getName` so that inheritors of this class implement this method for getting their own name. Hence the class itself must be an abstract class as well.

```
public abstract class CandyBox {
    
    private final double height, width;
    
    public CandyBox(double height, double width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
    
    public abstract String getName();
    
    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    
    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getName());
        sb.append(" { [height:").append(getHeight()).append("], [width:").append(getWidth()).append("] }");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Now that we have our base class we will create its inheritors `Baravelli`, `ChocoAmor` and `Lindt` respectively.

```
public class Baravelli extends CandyBox {
    
    public Baravelli(double height, double width) {
        super(height, width);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}


public class ChocoAmor extends CandyBox {
    
    public ChocoAmor(double height, double width) {
        super(height, width);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class ChocoAmor extends CandyBox {
    
    public ChocoAmor(double height, double width) {
        super(height, width);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

All inherited from the `CandyBox` class and its `toString` implementation. So these 3 classes know how to generate their string representation.
Let's proceed and create the `CandyBag` class which will inherit from the `CandyBox` class as well but override the `toString` method to implemnt it for its needs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CandyBag extends CandyBox {
    
    private final List<CandyBox> candyBoxes = new ArrayList<CandyBox>();
    
    public CandyBag(double height, double width) {
        super(height, width);
        candyBoxes.add(new Lindt(3.2, 9.2));
        candyBoxes.add(new Baravelli(3.3, 10.4));
        candyBoxes.add(new ChocoAmor(3.4, 11.6));
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = super.toString();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        sb.append("\n").append(getName()).append("'s contents: { \n\t");
            for (int i = 0; i < candyBoxes.size(); i++) {
                CandyBox cb = candyBoxes.get(i);
                sb.append("[").append(cb.toString()).append("]");
                String ending = i < candyBoxes.size()-1 ? "\n\t" : "\n";
                sb.append(ending);
            }
            sb.append("]}");
            return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here it has three fixed candy boxes that created once when it is instantiated (in its consructor method). It also overrode the `toString` method because it has to add its candy content to its string representation.
The 99% of the job is done so far. Now it is time to test it. Let's test it in a main class, let's create 1 `CandyBag` object and print its string representation.

```
public class MainClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Here we go...");
        CandyBag candyBag = new CandyBag(4, 20);
        System.out.println(candyBag.toString());
    }
    
}
```

See the output:

```
Here we go...
CandyBag { [height:4.0], [width:20.0] }
CandyBag's contents: { 
    [Lindt { [height:3.2], [width:9.2] }]
    [Baravelli { [height:3.3], [width:10.4] }]
    [ChocoAmor { [height:3.4], [width:11.6] }]
]}
```

You can play with the `toString` implementation to change the string representation form for your convenience. Go ahead and try this implementation and let me know if you hit your goal or fail for some reason.